# netplan doesnt set static IP address

Tags: networking, netplan

I need two wifi interfaces running of a single wifi card. One to stream into a local network with a static IP (wlan0) and one to access the internet with dhcp (internet).

I added the second interface (internet) by creating `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-wireless.rules` and running this

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="ieee80211", KERNEL=="phy0", \
    RUN+="/usr/bin/iw phy %k interface add internet type station"
```

For this I came up with the netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.188.107/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.188.1
      access-points:
        "SSID1":
          password: "***"
    internet:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      access-points:
        "SSID2":
          auth:
            ***

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [wlan0]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
```

Now the internet interface works like its supposed to but wlan0 does not get its static IP and I dont know why. How can I make it work?